# get spid of currently running stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

so, I have a proc that is essentially a dynamic query generator... depending on the complexity of the query the user set up i may wind up in a situation where the query may take 20+ minutes to execute.

so, to preface this question with some things I'm already doing to avoid these suggestions:

1. This is a dynamic query generator so the user can end up creating an extremely complicated custom query through the UI.  I add indexes and such when I see time spikes in a log I keep.
2. I am updating statistics on tables this leverages.
3. I have optimized the proc and associated tables as much as possible...

I have the timeout on my site set extremely high currently (8 minutes) to accommodate this, but what I'd like to do is kick long running calls to this proc over to a queue to run outside the app.

What I'm wondering is if when calling a stored procedure or more specifically dynamic sql, is there a way to get a handle to the spid that is created for the query?  Like, I imagine, in sql server management studio the stop button essentially is taking advantage of a function similar to this to kill the currently running query...  I'd be able to abort the query at a lowered timeout then have it run independently (perhaps even on a different server) and just email the results or something... any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can get current running spid using **@@spid**

Here is the msdn link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189535.aspx

Comment: thanks!  do you know if there is a way to reserve the spid or specify it through the procedure call?  it'd be nice if i could launch the query knowing the spid beforehand so I can have a watcher on the outside sp_kill it if he runs too long... no biggie, I think ultimately everything will need to run through the queue instead of my planned pushing the sql crushers there...

Comment: @zach, there is no way to reserve spid, but you can store current spid value in a table, the clean up stored procedure can check for active spids using the table and can kill long running spids.